# Process builder flow getting partially deployed through change set

Tags: deployment, process-builder, change-set

I've written a process builder flow with some conditions where the action is calling an @invocable Apex class. Now, when I'm moving this through change set to higher environments there the flow is getting deployed only partially. Surprisingly the action for the first condition is blank in the target org even though I didn't get any errors while deploying.
Any idea what I'm missing here?

P.S- Both the orgs are Spring'16.

Answer (score 1):

If the process calls an @invocable, you'll want to deploy the @invocable class first in one change set, the deploy the process in a second change set afterward. The class it's calling needs to already exist in the org for you to be able to reference it in your process when you deploy it. Ditto for any fields or other conditions that it references.

Comment: Why exactly can't you deploy both components and execute testing on one deploy? I mean I understood what happens but i'm just curious to know why.

Comment: PB will look for the reference and won't be able to find it. The reference won't be the same in the SB as it is in the next org or Production. Until that reference is established, it won't get associated as needed. You're not able to control the order that happens in when using a change set.

Comment: Whenever I'm adding the components to the change set and migration starts automatically on its own the action call of the flow in the source org is getting removed!!
Strange things are happening.I really can't find a plausible reason.

Comment: Wait a min. The source org? Haven't heard of that one!

Comment: Yes source org.
So what is the workaround? Do I've to do this manually?

Comment: I'd do a search on this. Truly haven't heard of it happening in the source org. Have only heard of issues in the target org.

Comment: It is strange indeed. After deployment I went in to see in the target org and the action was missing. Then I checked in source, and saw the same action is missing in source also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40829/discussion-between-sagnik-and-crmprogdev).